# Ajax reaction form via Typoscript not configured

Tags: ajax, typo3, typoscript

Via Typoscript I want to handle a reaction form with ajax. I have configured the page with the Typoscript code shown below.

But I keep getting the Typo3 error that the page is not configured?

## 1294587217: The page is not configured! [type=15191][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=15191 configured.

```
ajaxComments = PAGE 
ajaxComments {   
    typeNum = 15191   
    config.tx_realurl_enable = 0   
    config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1   
    config.disablePrefixComment = 1   
    config.metaCharset = UTF-8   
    config.no_cache = 1   
    config.additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json

    10 = USER   
    10 {
       userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
       pluginName = backend
       extensionName = extName
       controller = Main
       vendorName = venName
       action = sendComment
       switchableControllerActions {
          Main{
             1 = sendComment
          }
       }
       settings =< plugin.tx_extName.settings
       persistence =< plugin.tx_extName.persistence
       view =< plugin.tx_extName.view   
   } 
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be working. Try to start with clearing all caches (so trigger the `clear caches` button in the Install Tool and also check if the given TypoScript is loaded `as a setup` on the page where you fire the `?type=`).... The best way is just to put this in your `ROOT` template to make sure no other TypoScript thing / relation or something like that is punishing you..

Comment: Thanks Arek, indeed some other typoscript code was messing it up